# Scala mongo driver. Convert List[Document] to single Document

Tags: mongodb, scala

How does one merge a lot of documents into a single one?
I am now using the following construction:

```
// List(Document("a" -> 1 ) , Document("b" -> 2 ) , ... )
val answSeq: List[Document] = ??? 

var retDocument: Document = answSeq.foldRight(Document()) {
    (x,y) => x ++ y
}
```

But as I see in the source code, there is a possibility to create `Document` from `Iterable[Document]` ( not directly but something very near to it )

```
def apply(elems: CanBeBsonElements): Document = {
```

This may be more readable.
But I don't know how to use it.

Comment: what do you mean by merge? do you want to do a sort of map reduce?

Comment: merge for me is just sum: Document("a" -> 1 ) ++ Document("b" -> 1 ). 
like answSeq.foldRight in my question. Its not a problem to do it - i am just looking more canonical way.

Answer (score 0):

Document.fromSeq function has the behaviour that i needed.